# Would this question be closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to bring this here before actually asking it, as it seems to be one of those borderline questions that I could see as potentially being closed due to being too broad:

> How many punctuation marks can you place in a row and have it still be grammatical?
>
> This sentence is an example (which I thought, "How silly.").

The above statement uses four punctuation marks in a row at the end of the sentence.

Other exchange sites, such as Code Golf, would welcome questions like this with open arms. Would this site as well, or is it better left here on meta?

Comment: Code Golf is the exception rather than the rule for SE sites. As to your specific question, I don't think it is too broad. It is very specific. My thought is "Who cares?" but that doesn't mean it isn't topical. I'm open to it if the community doesn't object.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "an infinite number", because you can do something like this (I will explain how in these brackets (but the brackets can be repeated ad infinitum (even though it is totally unreadable))). You can do the same thing with quotation marks.

At any rate, this question is more about creativity than about solving an actual problem or answering an academic question, so I am inclined to say it would be closed.

Note also that brackets and quotation marks are not technically punctuation, only `,;:.?!`

Comment: That depends on what one’s definition of punctuation is. For some people, *lol* appears to be a mark of punctuation; for others, only the ellipsis alone is used.

Comment: Two additional points.... You don't even need brackets or quotation marks.... Because for some people, every period is an infinite number of periods..... Not to mention exclamation marks!!!!!1!LOL!!! And the second point....... Punctuation is not about grammaticality anyway. So the answer is "an infinite number" *by definition*. ThI!!!!!s Sen,,,,,,,,tence is an oooofull mess orthographically, but IT is grammaticalllllllllllly impeccable!!!!!!!!111LOL!!!!......

Comment: @RegDwigt: *peck* Not so impeckable.